# How to integrate over a sphere in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ how I can calculate the integral $\int_{\partial B(0,1)}{f(y)}dy$?

---

I tried to do this: let be $p:\left[0,2\pi\right]\to\partial B(0,1)$ such that $p(x)=\left(\cos(x),\sin(x)\right)$ and:

$$\int_{\partial B(0,1)}{f(y)}dy=\int_0^{2\pi}f(p(x))dx$$ but I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: There are some inconsistency here. Look that you say the domain of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, on the other hand the image of $p(x)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so... What actually is $f(p(x))$ ??

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari I'm sorry,  was a typo

Comment: Near as I can tell, with $f(y)$ denoting $f(y_1,y_2)$, you’re thinking about simple polar coordinates and $\int_{\partial B} \,f(y)\, dy = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\,d\theta$.

Comment: $y$ is a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we try to compute $\int_{\partial B(0,1)}{f(y)}dy$, we should be clear on what it means. One simple way to define it is as the line integral of $f$ along the curve $\partial B(0,1)$. In this case, applying the definition of a line integral, using your parameterization $p(x) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$, we have,

$$\int_{\partial B(0,1)}{f(y)}dy = \int_{0}^{2 \pi}{f(p(x))} |p'(x)|dx = \int_{0}^{2 \pi}{f(p(x))}dx$$

because $|p'(x)| = \sqrt{(-\sin(x))^2 + \cos^2(x)} = 1$.

So in short, your formula is correct, but be careful about the "change of variables" part.